# How can I test the retry logic of a begin-rescue block using Minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, race-condition, minitest

Suppose there's a service that consumes `processA`, an idempotent process that when called is expected either find or create a `Payment` record and return it.

```
class processA
  attr_reader :payment

  def initialize(operation_id)
    @payment = Payment.find_or_initialize_by(operation_id: operation_id)
  end

  def call
    update_payment_attributes
    payment.save!
  end

  private

  def update_payment_attributes
    # assign/update payment attributes
  end
end
```

Given it's idempotence, `processA` looks for an existing record that matches the given `operation_id`, but if none is found it instantiates one with said property, saves it and returns it.

If no `Payment` record that matches the passed `operation_id` is found and a new `Payment` creation starts, there's a slight chance that a race condition might happen with `processB` which might create a `Payment` with the same `operation_id` faster than it takes `processA` to complete the task.

If this happens, by the time the new `Payment` is saved in `processA` an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` error is raised due to some model constraint preventing two `Payment` records with the same `operation_id`.

**Problem:**

I've got some retry logic in the service `processAConsumer` so in the eventuality that an error is raised by `processA`, it's simply called a second time so the `Payment` created by `processB` is found and returned.

```
class processAConsumer
  
  def call(operation_id)
    begin
      retries ||= 0
      payment = processA.new(operation_id).call
    rescue PG::UniqueViolation, ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
      retry if (retries += 1) < 3
    end
  end
end
```

Using Minitest, how could I test this retry logic? Is there a way to Stub the first `processA` `#call` so it raises an error and the retry logic kicks in?

I've tried different things that look something like this, to no success:

```
test "retry logic should succeed" do
    processA.any_instance.expects(:call) do
      1.times do
        raise PG::UniqueViolation, ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
      end
    end

    response = processAConsumer.call(123)

    assert response.success? # fails because the retry logic is not kicking in.
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Foranyone wondering, this is what I used to test the retry logic:

```
  test "should retry on PG::UniqueViolation exception" do
    payment = payments(:some_payment) # payment fixture

    processA.any_instance
      .stubs(:call)
      .raises(PG::UniqueViolation)
      .then.returns(payment)

    response = processAConsumer.call(123)

    assert response.success?
  end
```

This makes the first `processA` `#call` return a `PG::UniqueViolation` error. The retry logic kicks in, and an instance of `Payment` is returned the second time `processA` `#call` is invoked.